# Iterm2: ^[[A, ^[[B Appearing on python3 interpreter

Tags: iterm2, python3, macos-mojave

I am using macOS Mojave and Iterm2: 3.2.7beta4. This is an issue I am seeing with python3 interpreter. When I type the arrow keys to move the cursor or to run the last command, I see

`^[[A, (with up key) ^[[B (with down)`

instead on the terminal. Its not the case with python2. I have checked the key bindings on iterm and nothing seems to be causing this. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could be missing readline.  `Pip install readline` Or if you have brew `brew install readline`  Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229934/1684474